# Dashboard Design in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, dashboard

I have below kind of dashboard in my app which i would like to design in Android. But I am not able to create it same as its in design.

Here is the design...[image]

**NOTE - Used 6 buttons named as one, two, three and so on. Also I have common header for which i user ViewStub. And I have created 320x480 round circle like below and set that as background image and placing the buttons accordingly. This is the approach i used.**

Layout Code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" >

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/vsHeader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inflatedId="@+id/headings"
            android:layout="@layout/header" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/categories"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/banner" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:contentDescription="desc"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/logo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/truck_button"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicker" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:background="@drawable/two"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicker" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/two"
            android:layout_below="@+id/two"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/tire_button"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicker" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/two"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/two"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/tow_truck_button"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicker" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/three"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/three"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
            android:background="@drawable/trailer_button"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicker" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/one"
            android:layout_below="@+id/five"
            android:background="@drawable/six"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicker" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**If anyone has any idea about this please kindly help or provide your valuable suggestion.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to create your own `CustomView` and track the click at `onTouch`, otherwise you:

1. Prepare different segments on the UI - atleast 4-6
2. align them using relative layouts
3. have their separate backgorund property which you would want to expand when trying on different resolutions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't have any idea about custom view. I am going to google it for the tutorial but if you have any reference than please kindly provide.

Comment: Just a thought, If you are good with web technologies, you can make such a dashboard in few hours for android with CSS3 and then connect with using a Chrome bridge.

Comment: the link has almost everything you want to build http://developer.samsung.com/android/samples-4